# Can't parse response from server

Tags: android, json, http, parsing

I have am doing a simple login page. I am sending over a username field and a password field. I see on the server these parameters are being passed in correctly and then the server gives back a json response. If HTTP is 200 then I parse the response and to get the message it works fine. If the status is 401 if I try to parse the message I get an IOException immediately.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.91:3000/api/login");

                JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();

                postDataParams.put("username", getUsername());
                postDataParams.put("password", getPassword());

                Log.e("params", postDataParams.toString());

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(30000 /* milliseconds */);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();    

                Log.e("responseCode", ""+responseCode);

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return result.toString();

                }
                else if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {

                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String line = "";

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    return result.toString();

                }
                else {
                    return new String("false : " + responseCode);
                }
            }  catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                return new String("false : MalformedURLException ");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return new String("false : IOException ");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return new String("false : JSONException ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new String("false : Exception1 ");
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    try {
                        conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        return new String("false : Exception2 ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The server is a nodejs server which returns the following response no matter what the HTTP status is:

```
router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log('Message returned ' + err.status + " " + err.message);
    res.status(err.status || params.ERROR_HTTP_INTERNAL).json(JSON.stringify({
        error: err.message
    }));
})
```

I do not think it has anything to do with the server because when using postman to make REST calls I am getting the proper response code and I can see the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

A 400 means something in your request was wrong.  In that case, there won't be a body passed back.  You need to figure out why the server is sending back 400 (does it send a 400 if the login data is invalid?).  At any rate, don't try to parse the body on 400, treat it as an error.

Comment: The server is sending the 400 code, but along with that it is sending a body which is a JSON object - error: "some message". I can confirm this because if I use another program such as postman to make rest calls I can see the body is included. I need to be able to get into the error field

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer out. Since it is an error that is being return I need to change this:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```

to this:

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getErrorStream());
```

Answer (score -2):

you'd better use [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library for RESTAPI

and I want to recommend to study asynchronous

Comment: Im not sure what the benefit of the library is? I would then rather prefer to use the official android library HttpURLConnection. This code is running in an AsyncTask